# Memory Crash when detecting object with MLModel

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, mlmodel

I have made an MLModel in CreateML that will detect hockey pucks in images. I use the camera on the phone to take a video, and while it is being recorded, I convert each frame to a CGImage and try to detect pucks in each frame.
At first when I received the memory crashes, I tried removing a trajectory detection I was running at the same time, however this made no change. When monitoring the memory usage during runtime, my app uses a small and consistent amount of memory; it is "Other processes" that goes over the limit, which is quite confusing. I also removed a for loop that filtered out objects with low confidence (below 0.5) but this does not have an effect either.

Being new to MLModel and machine learning, can anybody steer me in the right direction? Please let me know if any more details are needed, if I missed something.I will attach all of the code because it is only 100 lines or so, and it may be important for context. However, the initializeCaptureSession method and captureOutput method would probably be the ones to look at.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import ImageIO
import Vision

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    
    var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var camera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var microphone: AVCaptureDevice?
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    var videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    var audioDataOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
    
    @IBOutlet var trajectoriesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var pucksLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initializeCaptureSession()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    
    // Lazily create a single instance of VNDetectTrajectoriesRequest.
    private lazy var request: VNDetectTrajectoriesRequest = {
        request.objectMinimumNormalizedRadius = 0.0
        request.objectMaximumNormalizedRadius = 0.5
        return VNDetectTrajectoriesRequest(frameAnalysisSpacing: .zero, trajectoryLength: 10, completionHandler: completionHandler)
        
    }()

    // AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate callback.
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput,
                       didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        // Process the results.

        do {
            let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cmSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer)
            guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else{
                print("cannot make pixelbuffer for image conversion")
                return
            }
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
            let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)
            let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
            let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)
            let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer)
            let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
            let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue)
            guard let context = CGContext(data: baseAddress, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) else{
                print("cannot make context for image conversion")
                return
            }
            guard let cgImage = context.makeImage() else{
                print("cannot make cgimage for image conversion")
                return
            }
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
            let model = try VNCoreMLModel(for: PucksV7(configuration: MLModelConfiguration()).model)
            
            
            let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model)
            let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, options: [:])
            try? handler.perform([request])
            
            guard let pucks = request.results as? [VNDetectedObjectObservation] else{
                print("Could not convert detected pucks")
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.pucksLabel.text = "Pucks: \(pucks.count)"
            }
            
            try requestHandler.perform([request])
        } catch {
            // Handle the error.
        }
    }

    func completionHandler(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
        //identify results
        guard let observations = request.results as? [VNTrajectoryObservation] else { return }
        // Process the results.
        self.trajectoriesLabel.text = "Trajectories: \(observations.count)"
    }
    
    func initializeCaptureSession(){
        session.sessionPreset = .hd1920x1080
        camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
        microphone = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
        
        do{
            session.beginConfiguration()
            
            //adding camera
            let cameraCaptureInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera!)
            if session.canAddInput(cameraCaptureInput){
                session.addInput(cameraCaptureInput)
            }
            
            
            //output
            let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "output")
            if session.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) {
                videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
                videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
                videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
                session.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
                
            }
            
            let captureConnection = videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)
            // Always process the frames
            captureConnection?.isEnabled = true
            do {
                try camera!.lockForConfiguration()
                camera!.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            
            session.commitConfiguration()
            
            cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
            cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
            cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = view.bounds
            cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
            
            view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                self.session.startRunning()
            }
  
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Execution speed. You are dispatching threads faster than they can be processed.

In my experience, not on this platform, object detection using a cnn is not fast enough to process every frame from the camera in real-time at 30 fps.

With hardware acceleration, like the "Apple Neural Engine", it is possible (I have an FPGA on my desk that does this task in real time in "hardware" using 15 watts).

I would suggest processing every 50th frame and speed it up until it fails.

The other issue is image size. To be performant the image must be as small as possible and still detect the feature.

The larger the input image, the more convolution layers are required. Most models are in the smaller ranges like 200x200 pixels.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your answer. Earlier today I actually found the solution to my problem, and it was that for every frame, I was re-declaring the VNCoreML request, which was completely unnecessary. The solution was to have an empty variable of it, and declare the request in viewDidAppear, then assign it to the variable which i can use over and over again. What is crazy is that there is no memory problem, even while detecting for every frame, after using this new method. Shows how powerful hardware has become. However, thank you for your advice in memory management!

Comment: Also, I turned on "discard late frames" in the capture session, so I doubted it would be some sort of frame overload. I will give you the bounty however since I cannot give it to myself, and you gave some good advice going forward :)